# Are there any academic books or articles which analyzes popular manga?(Fight scenes)

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

I'm wondering if there's any book which analyses popular manga for instance the battle scenes or the romance. I know there's books on, "How to draw manga." Which would be the come the closest. I'm wondering if there are any book going further and analyzing how popular manga(Dragon ball, Naruto, HunterxHunter) draw their characters...etc.

Comment: Related: [Academic papers about anime & manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13515/2516) (but not specific to fighting scenes)